# Loading order of bootstrap javascripts

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

i'v been running in trouble, with my Bootstrap contact form. It seems to be important at which time the javascript files are loaded.
Depending on the placement some things doesn't work correctly:

If so:

```
<script src="js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

my contact form will don't work. Click on "SUBMIT"-Button and nothing happens. But the collapse menu button of bootstrap works fine.

If loading order is like this:

```
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
```

the contact form (especially the subimt button) works as expected. But the collapse 
bootstrap menu button don't work fine. It is unclickable.

I tried everything but I don't know the reason for that behavior. 
Do you have an idea, how to make both things work each other?

Here come's my full code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no"> 
    <title>Contact Form</title>
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
</head>

<body>
    <div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top" data-activeslide="1">
      <div class="container">
      <!-- .navbar-toggle is used as the toggle for collapsed navbar content -->
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-responsive-collapse">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
       <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>

      <div class="nav-collapse collapse navbar-responsive-collapse">
        <ul class="nav row"> 
           <li data-slide="1" class="col-12 col-sm-2"><a id="menu-link-1" href="#slide-1"> <span class="text">MENU 1</span></a></li>
           <li data-slide="2" class="col-12 col-sm-2"><a id="menu-link-2" href="#slide-2"> <span class="text">MENU 2</span></a></li>
         </ul>
         <div class="row">
           <div class="col-sm-2 active-menu"></div>
         </div>
      </div><!-- /.nav-collapse -->
      </div><!-- /.container -->
    </div><!-- /.navbar -->

    <div class="slide story" id="slide-1" data-slide="1">
      <div class="container">
       <div class="row">
         <div class="col-12">
           <p>TEST</p>
         </div>           
       </div>
     </div><!-- /container -->
   </div>

    <div class="slide story" id="slide-2" data-slide="2">
      <div class="container">
       <div class="row">
         <div class="col-12">
           <div class="well">
             <form id="contact-form" class="form">
               <fieldset>
               <legend>Contact Form</legend>
                 <div class="form-group">
                   <label for="name" class="control-label">Name</label>  
                   <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name1" placeholder="name"/>              
                 </div>
                 <div class="form-group">
                   <label for="name" class="control-label">E-Mail</label>
                   <input type="text" class="form-control" id="email" name="email" placeholder="email"/>   
                 </div>
                 <div class="form-group">
                   <label for="name" class="control-label">Phone</label>
                   <input type="text" class="form-control" id="phone" name="phone" placeholder="phone"/>   
                 </div>
                 <div class="form-group">
                   <label for="name" class="control-label">message</label>
                   <textarea type="text" id="message" class="form-control"  name="message" rows="10" cols="40" placeholder="Message"></textarea>
                 </div>
                 <div class="form-group">
                   <button value="Send" class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" id="submit" name="submit">Send</button>      
                   <button type="reset" class="btn">Clear</button> 
                 </div>
               </fieldset>
             </form>
           </div>
         </div>           
       </div>
     </div><!-- /container -->
   </div>



  <!-- Java-Scripts -->
  <script src="js/html5shiv.js"></script>
  <script src="js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/jquery.easing.1.3.js"></script>
  <script src="js/script.js"></script>
  <script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.11.1/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/val55.js"></script>

 </body>
</html>
```

This is what the val55.js-File looks like:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#contact-form").validate({
        rules: {
            name1:{
                minlength: 3,
                maxlength: 20,
                required: true
            },
            email:{
                minlength: 3,
                required: true,
                email: true
            },
            phone:{
                minlength: 3,
                required: true
            },
            message: {
                minlength: 10,
                required: true
           }         
        },
        highlight: function(element) {
            $(element).closest('.form-group').removeClass('has-success').addClass('has-error');
        },
        unhighlight: function(element) {
            $(element).closest('.form-group').removeClass('has-error').addClass('has-success');
        },
        submitHandler: function(form) {
        //form.submit();
          alert('Hallo');
        }
    })
}); // end document.ready
```

Regards,
John

Answer (score 0):

Do this:

```
  <script src="js/html5shiv.js"></script>
  <script src="js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.11.1/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/script.js"></script>
  <script src="js/val55.js"></script>
```

You might need to switch between the last to scripts and everything should work fine provided you don't have any errors in your javascript.

Comment: Hi Lucky Soni,

i've tested your suggested order. The Collapse Menu is OK.
But the Submit-Button dont do anything.

To see if Submit button (submitHandler) works correctly I just take an alert into: submitHandler: function(form) {alert('Hallo');}

Regards,
John

Comment: interesting is: the validate of the input fields are OK! But only the Submit Button don't do anything! John.

Comment: Removing data-slide="2" on <div class="slide story" id="slide-2" data-slide="2">, will solve the problem. But then the menu don't work.

Comment: hey John.. the problem is something else not the order of your javascript files.. Do you have a live URL to the website in question?